# AngularJS, What kind of $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have started with angular but I have some problem with kind of object in angular. 
[What kind of $scope in this screen? and how to get 'title' in that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpbQ8.png)
Here is my code.

```js
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route'], function(angularAMD) {
  var app = angular.module("coreModule", ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/home", angularAMD.route({
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          title: 'Home',
          controllerUrl: 'ctrl/home',
        })).
      when("/list", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: 'views/news.html',
        controller: 'newsCtrl',
        controllerUrl: 'ctrl/news'
      })).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true,
      });
    }
  ]);

  app.run(['$rootScope', '$route',
    function($rootScope, $route) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        console.log($rootScope);
      });
    }
  ]);

  app.factory('Page', function() {
    var title = 'default';
    return {
      title: function() {
        return title;
      },
      setTitle: function(newTitle) {
        title = newTitle;
        console.log(title);
      }
    };
  });


  return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

I want to get 'title' from controller.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Could you please paste the code here and by the looks of it, title is already on the scope. Where do you want to get it ??

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what you are trying to do but here is my guess.

If you are trying to set the page title from the controller then here is how I would do it. And that is Not set it from the controller. I would set it on the state as you have already done and then pick it up on every state change.

```
aspStratMed.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope)
{
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState)
    {
        if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle)
            $rootScope.pageTitle = toState.data.title;
    });
```

And then in the HTML just use this where every you need the page title

```
{{pageTitle}}
```

Comment: I did it before but $rootScope.pageTitle just working in template like  'home.html' or news.html. not working at root template. Example: {{pageTitle}} <div ng-view><div>. {{pageTitle}} not working.